# img tag with a content CSS attribute browser compatibility

Tags: css, standards-compliance

```css
.square {
  content: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAPcAAP8MAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAIAAgAAAINQABCBxIsKDBgwgTKlzIsKHDhxAjSpxIsaLFixgzatzIsaPHjyBDihxJsqTJkyhTqlzJUmRAADs=');
}
```

```html
There should be a red square below.
<br>
<img class="square">
```

My expectation is that the above code would display a red square, like this:

[image: picture of the above HTML code with a red square]

WebKit-based browsers such as Chrome, Opera and Konqueror seem to display it as expected. But Firefox, Seamonkey, Edge and Internet Explorer 11 don't display the red square (they display nothing).<sup>1</sup>

The `content` CSS attribute is covered by the [CSS 2.2 specification section 12.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-CSS22-20160412/generate.html#content).
Which browsers are correctly following the specification?

---

<sup>1</sup> Latest stable versions of all browsers were used for testing.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106155/how-did-css-content-property-work-for-img-element-in-webkit

Comment: it states `Applies to: :before and :after pseudo-elements ` and you are not using in pseudo element

Comment: css content property is used in conjunction with ::before or ::after. Use .square::after { content: url("...."); }

Comment: @TanvirAhmed he know this and it's clearly stated in the spec, but why it works for img then? this is the question

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Using `::after` makes it work on Firefox, but doesn't work on Chrome and Edge.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Correct! My question was indeed rather which of the browsers are correctly following the spec.

Comment: even if it works in chrome since almost ever, this is a bad idea. it is not meant to swap the content of a tag( could be an entire site) to something else ... how surprised you would be landing on a site from google and finding something else at screen . I am actually surprised that it still works in webkit browsers ....

Comment: @G-Cyr am pretty sure it's only limited to img tag to allow image replacing using only CSS ... content never worked for me with any other tags

Comment: That duplicate target seems to be more concerned with a specific implementation of the content property for actual elements rather than the general idea of the content property being supported in actual elements. Oddly enough, the answer to that question is stolen from an answer *that I remember word-for-word* to [another question from 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173991/content-attribute-of-img-elements) which serves as a more suitable duplicate target.

Comment: @TemaniAfif it Never dis actually. Only To show how bad i think it is. It was maybe usefull at one point if srcset  was not avalaible yet.

Comment: @Temani Afif about "but why it works for img then?" - I could not find any good solution using css content for this scenerio yet. I agree with G-Cyr, and think that we cannot rely on setting image src this way, unless there's support for src in content.

Comment: And I would go for div with background image css property to be browser friendly.

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I also agree with G-Cyr, but the question is not how to rely on it or not, but why it's working ... why Chrome allow such thing to happen when it shouldn't. I know there is a lot better way to do an I pesonally never use such technique